# Stopping an exe file from being run C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating an application to manage other applications or exe files on a user's computer, and stop them from accessing them at certain times (like ColdTurkey's application blocking feature).

The way I am trying to do this has not been working so far - I attempted to do this by opening the file **dwShareMode** set to 0 using the **CreateFile** function. This seems to work for files such as text files and does not allow the file to be opened, however this is not the case if I try and do this same approach on exe files, and the user is free to open the file.

I assume that exe files are not 'read' in the same way by Windows as a text file is read by notepad and that that means setting the dwShareMode to 0 does not affect it being opened, however I do not know what the difference between these are. Any help would be appreciated.

Code here (for the text file):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE test;
    test = CreateFile("test.txt",
         GENERIC_WRITE,
         0,
         NULL,
         CREATE_NEW,
         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
         NULL);

    cout << "press enter to stop blocking application: ";
    string b;
    getline(cin, b); 
    cout << endl;
    CloseHandle(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***and stop them from accessing them at certain times*** I believe you will most likely have to do this at the system driver level.

Comment: You should definitely check for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as a return value to see if you're getting any error result.

Comment: Ordinary Windows security works down at the file level. I can  think of some reasons to do things in a hack-like way instead of just using the OS' services, but they're all nefarious reasons.

Comment: Another option is to use [the `AppInit_DLLs` registry key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197571/working-with-the-appinit-dlls-registry-value) to load a custom DLL into all (well, most) EXEs when they are first started. If the DLL returns FALSE from its `DllMain()` entry point, the calling process is aborted. Another option would be to use [WMI events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425.aspx) to detect when a new process is being started, and then you can terminate it if needed.  Or you can use something like [Eldos CallbackProcess](https://www.eldos.com/cbproc/) API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me to block execution of the file. You do need to specify `OPEN_EXISTING` instead of `CREATE_NEW` (because you're not trying to create a new file here).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a very silly error to make :)

Answer (score -1):

Not a windows expert -- I'm used to Unix/Linux and use the Cygwin package so I can program "in Unix" on my Windows desktop -- but it looks to me like you need to set the lpSecurityAttributes parameter, the one that comes *after* dwShareMode.

I think the following page might be helpful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364399(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `NULL` is a perfectly valid value for `lpSecurityAttributes`. From the page you linked to: "If you specify NULL for the lpSecurityAttributes parameter, the file or directory gets a default security descriptor."

Comment: Yes, but the default security descriptor allows EXECUTE access. Cole wants to _prevent_ users from executing the apps in question. In order to do that, he needs to modify the permissions.

Comment: The security descriptor in that function refers to the security attributes of the returned *handle*, not the permissions of the file on disk. Besides, there's no presumption that the blocker app has the permission to modify the execute permission of the executable on disk, but opening the file in a non-sharing mode would be fine.

Comment: Yes, but the default security descriptor allows EXECUTE access. Cole wants to _prevent_ users from executing the apps in question, so he needs to modify the permissions.

I like Remy Lebeau's proposed solution better *if* Cole has Admin privilege on the system.

*If* Cole has the ability to recompile the apps he wants to turn on and off, is to create a new DLL and rebuild the apps to contain a reference to that DLL(*). Then the DllMain() entry point can return false to make the app unavailable.

(*) -L$(dll-name) in Unix ld parameters, not sure what the equivalent is for Windows.

Comment: Greg Hewgill: good point about the security attributes of the handle vs. the file on disk.

I'm still favoring Remy Lebeau's solution.

Comment: Both this proposed answer as well as the comment trail are largely misleading. There is no need to recompile applications to have them load DLLs through the AppInit_DLLs registry key, for example. The other points have been clarified by Greg Hewgill.